# retrieving object from nib file

Tags: cocoa

I have a nib file. In this I created a new custom view (of type NSView) as an object in it. This object is not a child of the Default Window. I just wanted to retrieve this object. How could i do so.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an IBOutlet connection to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag to your view in the nib and retrieve it as below:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourNibName" owner:self options:nil];  
UIView *myView; 
for (NSObject *anObj in arr) {
    if([anObj isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {      
        if((UIView *)anObj.tag == yourTag) {
            myView = (UIView *)anObj;
    }
}
```